# How to get data of class uvtop product of a POT package analysis in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the [POT package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/POT/index.html) to carry out certain calculations in R. The output of the analysis is stored in a object of class `uvtop`. Now, I'd like to **export** the result of the analysis, rather than just plot it within an R window.

Here it goes an example, using sample data from this package.

```
data(ardieres)
events1 <- clust(ardieres, u = 6, tim.cond = 8/365, clust.max = TRUE)
npy <- length(events1[,"obs"]) / (diff(range(ardieres[,"time"], na.rm
= TRUE)) - diff(ardieres[c(20945,20947),"time"]))
mle <- fitgpd(events1[,"obs"], thresh = 6, est = "mle")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(mle, npy = npy)
```

With this, I get the image below:
[image: test output]

OK, but what I want is to export the necessary data to reproduce the Return Level Plot (bottom right panel) somewhere else, i.e. the values represented by circles, the solid and both dashed lines.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Read, for instance, [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It is almost surely possible to do what you want but we need much more information than just a package name and the object class. (Produced by function `fitgpd`?)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The third instruction `npy <- length(etc` is incomplete.

Comment: What do you mean by *"data to reproduce the Return Level Plot (bottom right panel) somewhere else"*? Does somewhere else mean: in R on someone else's computer, excel, python, SAS, etc.?

Comment: I have fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: @emilliman5, what I mean is that I want an ASCII file with the coordinates of the circles, other with the solid line, and other with the dashed lines. This way, I can reproduce the figure with whatever other plotting software I'm more familiar with.

Comment: What you are asking requires some detective work. First of all run `str(mle)` to know what is in the object to be plotted. Then, run `getAnywhere(plot.uvpot)`. This will tell you that the function that plots the 4th graph is `getAnywhere(retlev.uvpot)`. And if you now have the source code you can know what are the data structures you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data that is plotted for Return Level, we have to dig into the `retlev` function. Basically, I did my best to strip all of the plotting out and construct a data.frame of the required points.

```
getRetLevData <- function (fitted, npy) {
  data  <- fitted$exceed
  loc   <- fitted$threshold[1]
  scale <- fitted$param["scale"]
  shape <- fitted$param["shape"]
  n     <- fitted$nat

  pot.fun <- function(T) {
    p <- rp2prob(T, npy)[, "prob"]
    return(qgpd(p, loc, scale, shape))
  }

  eps <- 10^(-3)

  if (!is.null(fitted$noy)){ 
    npy <- n/fitted$noy
    } else if (missing(npy)) {
    warning("Argument ``npy'' is missing. Setting it to 1.")
    npy <- 1
  }

  xlimsup    <- prob2rp((n - 0.35)/n, npy)[, "retper"]
  fittedLine <- pot.fun(seq(1/npy + eps, xlimsup, length.out = n))
  p_emp      <- (1:n - 0.35)/n
  xPoints    <- 1/(npy * (1 - p_emp))
  empPoints  <- sort(data)
  samp       <- rgpd(1000 * n, loc, scale, shape)
  samp       <- matrix(samp, n, 1000)
  samp       <- apply(samp, 2, sort)
  samp       <- apply(samp, 1, sort)
  ci_inf     <- samp[25, ]
  ci_sup     <- samp[975, ]

  rst <- data.frame(xPoints, fittedLine, empPoints, 
                    ci_inf, ci_sup)
}

x <- getRetLevData(mle, npy)
head(x)
#    fittedX fittedLine  xPoints empPoints   ci_inf   ci_sup
#1  1.001000   6.003716 1.011535      6.09 6.001557 6.239971
#2  3.891288  11.678503 1.029810      6.09 6.014536 6.363070
#3  6.781577  14.402517 1.048758      6.09 6.042065 6.470195
#4  9.671865  16.282306 1.068416      6.19 6.074348 6.583290
#5 12.562153  17.740710 1.088825      6.44 6.114193 6.684118
#6 15.452441  18.942354 1.110029      6.45 6.146098 6.812058
write.csv(x, "my_pot_results.csv")
```

An overlay of the extracted data vs `retlev` plot. The CI's are a bit different because of sampling.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks like black magic to be, but it works. What puzzles me most is that '0.35'. Do you mind commenting on this part? Anyway, I'll try now to apply to my particular problem, and then I'll mark the question as solved.

Comment: I have no idea why `0.35` is used in the math or what the `pot.fun` does except call `rp2prob`.

Comment: Thanks, I it finally works, but it requires a final tweak (that took me several hours of desperation and reverse engineering to figure out). The x-coordinates for the fitted curve are different as for the dots and the dashed lines. I had to edit the function to output the two x-vectors, but it works nicely now. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that. That's why my function returns `fittedx` and `xpoints`, I should have made that more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read the file with other applications than R, just save it with:

```
save(mle, file="myfilename.Rdata")
```

or

```
saveRDS(mle, file="myfilename.Rds")
```

To read it back in, load the library that generated the data and then use

```
load("myfilename.Rdata")
```

to load the object back to your workspace or

```
mle <- readRDS("myfilename.Rds")
```

`save` saves more environments together with the object than `saveRDS` depending on how the library is implemented this might make a difference. I'd suggest to use `save` unless the datasets are getting too large.